# SQL Table has primary key but error "Diesel only supports tables with primary keys. Table errors has no primary key"

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Going through [diesel getting started](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started), but adjusting for Mysql, I've been able to get this to work, and then fail, and then work again, then fail.

Where I am:

up.sql

```
CREATE TABLE errors 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    matching_string VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    reference_url TEXT NOT NULL,
    reference_case TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

down.sql

```
DROP TABLE errors;
```

When I run diesel commands to get the schema file populated, I get...

```
sh-3.2$ diesel migration run
Diesel only supports tables with primary keys. Table errors has no primary key

sh-3.2$ diesel migration redo
Rolling back migration 2021-09-21-202330_create_posts
Running migration 2021-09-21-202330_create_posts
Diesel only supports tables with primary keys. Table errors has no primary key

sh-3.2$ diesel migration revert
Rolling back migration 2021-09-21-202330_create_posts

sh-3.2$ diesel migration run
Running migration 2021-09-21-202330_create_posts
Diesel only supports tables with primary keys. Table errors has no primary key
```

I've tried to delete all tables, including the __diesel_schema_migrations table, without success.

Comment: Have you tried with a simpler "create table"?

Comment: Diesel [uses the information_schema](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/09f8bcd78e3fb634ed69c66f46695b821a5b3822/diesel_cli/src/infer_schema_internals/information_schema.rs#L140-L165) provided by mysql to get information about the schema itself. This error message indicates that there is some mismatch between the information inside the information_schema and your actual schema. Can you verify that the information_schema contains the correct information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust Diesel is not recognizing primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430476/rust-diesel-is-not-recognizing-primary-key)