# Rust Diesel is not recognizing primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, rust, rust-diesel

This is my up.sql file:

```
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(255),
    `last_name` VARCHAR(255),
    `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

When I run diesel migration I receive the following error:

*Diesel only supports tables with primary keys. Table users has no primary key*

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up manually creating the table in mysql directly, however when I tried to generate the schema I once again received the "no primary key" error message from the diesel cli. So I began playing around with my sql to see if I could make it work, and eventually it did using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(255),
    `last_name` VARCHAR(255),
    `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

It seems that in order for diesel to recognize a column as having a PRIMARY KEY, the primary key attribute must be the last one specified.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, a known quirk, or valid syntax. In any case it was fairly annoying to track this down. I will do some more testing and accept this answer if it seems to be a robust solution.

(edit: I also tested this with a similar SQL query where AUTO_INCREMENT came after PRIMARY KEY, and it did not work)

Comment: Diesel uses the information schema provided by mysql to receive information about the current schema. This includes the table name, the corresponding information about any column and information about foreign and primary keys. If diesel cli emits a message saying there is no primary key for a certain table that's because there is no primary key listed in the information schema. Additionally this seems to be a highly platform depended issue. If you are interested in helping to fix this issue feel free to add information to the corresponding issue(https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2786)